# Migrating to Combine causes Snapshotlistener to fail

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, combine

I am migrating the codebase to Combine and the snapshotlistener isn't working i.e. when the document is updated in the back-end, it doesn't get reflected in the app.

This is where I call the service from the Controller:

```
@objc func loadPlans() {
    guard let userEmail = userEmail else { return }
    getPlansToken = PlanService.sharedInstance.queryPlans(userEmail: userEmail)
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink { (completion) in
        switch completion {
        case .failure(let error):
            self.showAlert(alertTitle: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
        case .finished:
            print("Publisher stopped observing")
        }
    } receiveValue: { (mealplans) in
        self.mealplanArray.removeAll()
        self.mealplanArray = mealplans.map({return PlanViewModel(mealplan: $0)})
        self.planTableView.reloadData()
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

And this is the service:

```
var listener : ListenerRegistration!
let db = Firestore.firestore()
static let sharedInstance = PlanService()

func queryPlans(userEmail: String) -> Future<[Mealplan], Error> {
    var mealplans = [Mealplan]()
    return Future { promise in
        self.listener = self.db.collection("Meal_Plans")
            .whereField("userId", isEqualTo: userEmail)
            .order(by: "timeOfCreation", descending: true)
            .addSnapshotListener({ (querySnapshot, error) in
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("No mealplans")
                    return
                }
                mealplans = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Mealplan? in
                    return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Mealplan.self)
                }
                promise(.success(self.updateTimeZone(source: mealplans)))
                if let error = error {
                    promise(.failure(error))
                }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that the `addSnapshotListener` never triggers even when updating a document that complies with the `whereField` restriction, is that so? Does it work without restricting the query with the "where" clause? Have you added some logging inside the callback to verify that it's not executing? Could you add some logging to verify that the listener is created? Do you get any error message?

Comment: Yes, the listener is created. When I update the DB, I know that the listener receive the update. However, either the updated value is NOT sent via the returned future OR it's not received as part of the receive value (I don't know which one). I've used the same function instead for a delegate function (which is what I am refactoring from) and it works just fine.

Comment: So you mean that the callback at `addSnapshotListener` is executed but the code inside it is not working fine? Or the problem is at `sink` or `receiveValue`? Could you add some logging to check what each of the involved functions is receiving and when they are being executed?

Comment: The problem is definitely at the sink and receiveValue. Yes, I added logging. They are executed, as expected in viewDidAppear but they do not get triggered when the document in the Firestore is updated. The snapshot listener is working just fine.

Comment: Have you tried to use the [CombineFirebase library](https://github.com/rever-ai/CombineFirebase)? I'm not proficient with Swift, but reading over their [sample snippets](https://github.com/rever-ai/CombineFirebase#firestore) I can see that they are using different methods to listen for changes on the database. Could you give it a try?

Comment: Hey @BVB09, did you figure out what was the problem? I am trying to do the same thing. My addSnapshotListener received the update from Firestore just fine. This is then returned as a Future<SomeObject, Never>. I sink this Future object in my UseCase layer... So when the sink is first called, it works with the init value of Future object. After that it does not run when the Future object is updated. I suspect that the somehow the new value put into the Future object is not recognized as a "new value", so it never got Published? Any thought?

Comment: I looked at the documentation and turns out Future always finishes after producing a value, so that explains why only the init values come through

Comment: I came across a similar issue, when I removed the second orderBy function the listeners continued to work without completing immediately.